# spark dataframe rolling window user define operation

Tags: apache-spark, aggregate-functions, apache-spark-sql

Is there a way to define user function for a rolling window design?
For Example, I know we can calculate average with rollover as follows -

```
val wSpec1 = Window.orderBy("c1").rowsBetween(-20, +20)
var dfWithMovingAvg = df.withColumn( "Avg",avg(df("c2")).over(wSpec1))
```

Now,In case I need to change average to custom function (`XYZ`), how do I do it? 
Like say for example,I need to perform +,-,+,- alternatively - that to over rolling window

```
val wSpec1 = Window.orderBy("c1").rowsBetween(-20, +20)
var dfWithAlternate = df.withColumn( "alter",XYZ(df("c2")).over(wSpec1))
```

Now How do I define the function XYZ? I know i can do it, but the challenge of syntax proved too tough. I did go through avg function, even that was very tough to understand.

Comment: Even if you could this won't work with `wSpec1` like this.

Comment: @LostInOverflow : Thanks for the comment, Could you help me with an example on how to use user defined function for rolling window. My example is not very accurately put in question. But I am wondering how to use UDF in rolling window.